# Clause where doesnt work qliksense

Tags: date, where-clause, qlikview, qliksense

I have a problem with qliksense. 
I cant charge my date with request sql oracle (more than million lines). 
I believe that  'where clause' with my DATE doesn't work. I want filter !

Can you help me to resolve this proble ?

2 case :
* No data charging
* Charging all lines

My hypothesis:
* data is corrupt
* bad parameter oracle / qlik sense

**My oracle parameter :**

```
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
```

**Parameter Qliksense :**

```
SET TimeFormat='hh:mm:ss';
SET DateFormat='DD/MM/YYYY';
SET TimestampFormat='DD/MM/YYYY'; /* DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss[.fff] */
```

**The script, DTTINS is type DATE :**

```
MATABLE:
Select 
IDTCTR
from dwh.matable 
where DTTINS >= '01/01/2016' ;

store MATABLE into $(qvdfait)matable.qvd (qvd);
```

This script work in sql/developper 
I have try everithing put DTTINS with to_char, to_number, to_date, 
change the Date format

Thx for your help

Comment: to_char(DTTINS,'DD/MON/YYYY') >= '01/JAN/2016' ?

Answer (score 1):

oracle dateformat is different from Qliks'. for example month in oracle is "MON" and not "MM".
In the load you have to specify the exact format you want to compare;

Use: `to_char(DTTINS,'DD/MON/YYYY') >= '01/JAN/2016' ;`